# vb .NET ComboBox populated from Dictionary holding a value from a Dataset

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

This is a form to maintain user privileges in an application based on MySQL. Each user has attributes e.g. name, position, entry date, etc. and also access privileges to three areas of the application: to "user maintenance", "supplier maintenance" and "order administration". Access privileges can be one of "no access", "read-only", "modify". They are kept in a Dictionary object.

On the form there are ComboBoxes for each area of the application where an access privilege needs to be assigned. The current access privileges are in the user record in the database table.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class _000Test

Private Enum AccessPrivilege
    no_access = 0
    read_only = 1
    modify = 2
End Enum

Private AccessList As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From _
    {{AccessPrivilege.no_access, "kein Zutritt"}, _
     {AccessPrivilege.read_only, "darf lesen"}, _
     {AccessPrivilege.modify, "darf bearbeiten"}}

Private Sub _000Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    OrderAdminComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(AccessList, Nothing)
    OrderAdminComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
    OrderAdminComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
    OrderAdminComboBox.DataBindings _
        .Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", UserBindingSource, "OrderAdmin", True))

    SupplierAdminComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(AccessList, Nothing)
    SupplierMaintComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
    SupplierMaintComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
    SupplierMaintComboBox.DataBindings _
        .Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", UserBindingSource, "SupplierMaint", False))

    OrderAdminComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(AccessList, Nothing)
    OrderAdminComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
    OrderAdminComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"
    OrderAdminComboBox.DataBindings _
        .Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", UserBindingSource, "OrderAdmin", True))

    Me.UserTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Bringadb_AppDS.User)

End Sub
```

The problem I have is that the comboboxes do not work. No matter what the values in the database record in the table are the combobox would display 0 - "no access". I also had the access privilege values in a table and set the DataSource property to it - same result.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what `UserBindingSource` is. Seem slike Binding cannot find value of `OrderAdmin` in the DataSource of the ComboBox

Comment: I have to translate all relevant information from German to English, so briefly: UserBindingSource is a System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource with DataSource set to the ProjectDatasource (i.e. the entire dabase) and DataMember set to the table named Users. The table among others contains an SByte Field for each access privilege, so for OrderAdmin. In MySQL Workbench the field OrderAdmin has the value 2, i.e. modif-access.

Comment: Is there a way to set something to get an email if a comment or answer has been submitted to my question?

Answer (score 1):

I think converting from database type `SByte` to `Integer`(Int32) fails.
Try add formatting to the binding object and use `Convert.ToInt32(value)` method for converting to `Int32`

```vb
OrderAdminComboBox.DataSource = New BindingSource(AccessList, Nothing)
OrderAdminComboBox.ValueMember = "Key"
OrderAdminComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value"

'Create binding object with Format event handler
Dim bindAccess As New Binding("SelectedValue", UserBindingSource, "OrderAdmin")
AddHandler bindAccess.Format, Sub(sender, e) e.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value))

OrderAdminComboBox.DataBindings.Add(bindAccess)
```

Comment: Danke Fabio! Das wars!! Nach zwei Tagen herumprobieren funzt plötzlich alles ganz geschmeidig! Ein tolles Gefühl. Danke nochmals, leider habe ich noch zuwenig Irgendwas, darf also die Antwort nicht als Antwort markieren. Bitte macht das jemand für mich.

Comment: Sorry, wrong language (was quite a long day...): 
Thank you, Fabio! After two days trying around everything works perfectly now!! I do not have enough something to mark Fabio's reply as the correct answer, so could somebody do that for me? Thank you.